# MAUI How to use base64 for SfAvatar ImageSource?

Tags: maui, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusions SfAvatar in my MAUI application.
From backend I get a image as base64.
The SfAvatar has the property ImageSource and I could bin a local image (..path/pic.png).

**How can I use the base64 as image at the SfAvatar?**

```
<sfavatar:SfAvatarView x:Name="Avatar" 
                       AvatarName="{Binding Initials}" 
                       ImageSource="{Binding Image}"
                       ContentType="Default" 
                       InitialsType="DoubleCharacter"
                       VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="100"
                       WidthRequest="100" CornerRadius="50"
                       Stroke="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
```

Comment: Did you try to use `ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image)))` to convert the base64 to image source?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.

```
var base64 = await _profileService.GetUserImageAsync();
var removeString = "data:image/png;base64,";
var index = base64.IndexOf(removeString);
var cleanPath = index < 0
    ? base64
    : base64.Remove(index, removeString.Length);

Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(cleanPath)));
```